# Type.GetType() returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, user-controls, gettype

I have a web application that dynamically creates a web page using usercontrols.

Within my code I have the following:

```
    private void Render_Modules()
    {
        foreach (OnlineSystemPageCustom.OnlineSystemPageHdr.OnlineSystemPageModule item in custompage.Header.Modules)
        {
            if (item.ModuleCustomOrder != 99 && !item.ModuleOptional)
            {
                string typeName = item.ModuleInternetFile;
                Type child = Type.GetType(typeName);
                webonlinecustombase ctl = (webonlinecustombase)Page.LoadControl("../IPAM_Controls/webtemplatecontrols/" + child.Name.ToString() + ".ascx");
                ctl.Event = Event;
                ctl.custompage = custompage;
                ctl.custommodule = item;
                this.eventprogrammodules.Controls.Add(ctl);
            }
        }
    }
```

The "typeName" that is being returned (example) is:

`IPAMIntranet.IPAM_Controls.webtemplatecontrols.eventorgcommittee`

The namespace for the user controls is as follows:

```
namespace IPAMIntranet.IPAM_Controls
```

The problem I am having is that Type.GetType(typeName) is returning null. What am I missing here?

Comment: yes sorry my typing error, I meant null

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) only looks in the currently executing assembly and `mscorlib` when you don't specify the assembly name within the string.

Options:

- Use the assembly-qualified name instead
- Call [`Assembly.GetType(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) on the appropriate assembly instead

If you have an easy way of getting hold of the relevant assembly (e.g. via `typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly`) then the second option is probably simpler.

Comment: assembly-qualified name? where do I get that? These are custom user controls that I created within the web application itself if that helps

Comment: @mattgcon: You can use `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`, but if you know it's for a specific assembly, you could use `typeof(SomeClassInTheAssembly).Assembly` to get that assembly, then use `Assembly.GetType(string)`. It doesn't matter which class you use from the assembly to get a reference to it.

Comment: After I get the assembly then what do I do? Do I state Type child = Assembly.GetType(typeName) to get the user control?

Comment: @mattgcon: Yes, exactly... except using the assembly reference instead of just `Assembly`.

Comment: ok so I added the following: 'Assembly aqn = typeof(webonlinecustombase).Assembly' then 'Type child = aqn.GetType(typeName)' but it is still returning null

Comment: @mattgcon: Then it sounds like either your type name is wrong, or that type isn't in the same assembly as `webonlinecustombase`. (Is that really the name of a type? You might want to look at the .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6356/discussion-between-mattgcon-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @mattgcon: Sorry, chat doesn't really work for my lifestyle. Let's stick to comments.

Comment: Ok not a problem. the type is being returned from a SQL database with a type such as: 'IPAMIntranet.IPAM_Controls.webtemplatecontrols.eventorgcommittee' the usercontrol that I created has a filename of eventorgcommittee.ascx. Both eventorgcommittee.ascx and webonlinecustombase.ascx are located within the same folder

Comment: @mattgcon: I don't know the details of on-the-fly compilation in ASP.NET - I suggest you try to open one of the generated assemblies in Reflector, and see what's in it. Alternatively, try to change your design so that you don't need quite this approach...

Comment: what I dont understand is, why do I need to call a different assembly if the user control files are not pre compiled from a dll and instead located as files within my web application.

Comment: @mattgcon: Well the types are being created on-the-fly... I'd hoped it would be compiling *all* of the user controls in one assembly, which would make it work... but if it only compiles them on a "just in time" basis, you'll end up with one assembly per control, which makes it all harder.

Comment: You are correct in the fact that it is one assembly per control. Here is a question, how would I take that string for the type and do a typeof(class) on it?

Comment: @mattgcon: You can't, because the type reference basically isn't known at compile-time - because it's compiled at execution time.

Comment: hmmm well that makes things more difficult then. and it has to be done this way.

Comment: @mattgcon: It's not clear exactly what you mean by that. Do you *have* to use non-precompiled user-controls? (If you precompiled them, they could all be in the same assembly.) Does the logic *have* to be in those user controls? You could have a class which basically used `typeof` for each user control you cared about, creating a mapping from string to type - but that would basically force the early compilation anyway.

Comment: oh what I meant was that the loading of the controls has to be at runtime. The webonlinecustombase is the base usercontrol for all of the dynamically loaded controls if that helps

Comment: I might have just solved my issue hold on and I will return with my results

Comment: Ok this was solved by simply putting stripping off everything except for the control name from typePath and placing it in the LoadControl statement.

Comment: @mattgcon: Ah, excellent - glad you sorted it in the end!

Comment: @skeet , using Assemly... gives error that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(string)'

Comment: @AKS: Hence the "on the appropriate assembly" part. You need to have a reference to the relevant `Assembly` first...

Answer (score 4):

Type.GetType looks as the *calling* assembly, and a few system assemblies. For anything else, you must either use `assemblyInstance.GetType(typeName)`, or you must use the "assembly qualified name" of the type, which includes the assembly details in which the type can be found. Otherwise, it wont be found, and will return null. You can get that from:

```
string aqn = someType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Comment: how do I get the assembly qualified name for the user controls

Comment: @mattgcon I included that in the answerr

Comment: if the someType is my typeName, I have to say that typeName is going to be dynamic and I have no idea what it is during design time.

Comment: @matt somewhere, somehow, you have some strings. What I am saying is: store them as the assembly-qualified version. Or: if they all come from the same dll, use Assembly.GetType

Comment: The thing is these are not precompiled usercontrols that I added with a dll. they are actual usercontrol files within the web application. They are located in a sub folder within the web application.

Comment: @web just create one, and see what the assembly-qualified-name is. IIRC they follow a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to the original poster, except that I needed to instantiate the code-behind class of my custom user-control in a static utility class rather than an ASPX page, so LoadControl wasn't available to me.  Here's what I ended up doing:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string MyFunc(string controlClassName)
    {
        string result = "";
        // get a list of all assemblies in this application domain
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        // the trouble is that we don't know which assembly the class is defined in,
        // because we are using the "Web Site" model in Visual Studio that compiles
        // them on the fly into assemblies with random names
        // -> however, we do know that the assembly will be named App_Web_*
        // (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163496.aspx)
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            if (assembly.FullName.StartsWith("App_Web_"))
            {
                // I have specified the ClassName attribute of the <%@ Control %>
                // directive in the relevant ASCX files, so this should work
                Type t = assembly.GetType("ASP." + controlClassName);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    // use reflection to create the instance (as a general object)
                    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    // cast to the common base type that has the property we need
                    CommonBaseType ctrl = o as CommonBaseType;
                    if (ctrl != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string key in ctrl.PropertyWeNeed)
                        {
                            // finally, do the actual work
                            result = "something good";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's not pretty and not very efficient, and is liable to break if the App_Web_* naming convention changes (although you could then just look through all of them): but it does work ...